# How to create applet that controls stop lights?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am working on a Java applet that will have three buttons:

- <kbd>Go</kbd>
- <kbd>Stop</kbd>
- <kbd>Slow</kbd>

The buttons will control a stoplight which in turn controls a car. At this point I am unable to get the stop light to change colors while keeping the switch statement mandated by the class. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class lights extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    JButton stop, go, slow;
    AudioClip ac;
    JPanel buttong;
    int x = 0;

    public void init() {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object obj = ae.getSource();

        if (obj == go) {
            x = 1;
        }

        if (obj == stop) {
            x = 2;
        } else if (obj == slow) {
            x = 3;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        stoplight(g, 50, 50);
        buttons();

        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillOval(50, 50, 10, 10);

                ac = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Hot rod start.wav");
                ac.play();
                break;
            case 2:
                x = 2;
                g.setColor(Color.red);

                g.fillOval(50, 70, 10, 10);
                break;
            case 3:
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);

                g.fillOval(x, 60, 10, 10);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void stoplight(Graphics grph, int x, int y) {
        Polygon box;
        box = new Polygon();
        box.addPoint(x, y);
        box.addPoint(x + 10, y);
        box.addPoint(x + 10, y + 30);
        box.addPoint(x, y + 30);
        grph.drawPolygon(box);
        grph.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
        grph.drawOval(x, y + 10, 10, 10);
        grph.drawOval(x, y + 20, 10, 10);
        Polygon pole;
        pole = new Polygon();
        pole.addPoint(x + 3, y + 30);
        pole.addPoint(x + 3, y + 70);
        pole.addPoint(x + 7, y + 70);
        pole.addPoint(x + 7, y + 30);
        grph.drawPolygon(pole);
    }

    public void buttons() {

        buttong = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        stop = new JButton("Stop");

        go = new JButton("Go");

        slow = new JButton("Slow");
        go.addActionListener(this);
        stop.addActionListener(this);
        slow.addActionListener(this);

        buttong.add(go);
        buttong.add(stop);
        buttong.add(slow);
        add(buttong);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: `ac = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"Hot rod start.wav" ); ac.play();` We should never try to load resources in a `paint()` method!  Better to move `ac = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"Hot rod start.wav" );` into the `init()` method.

Comment: DON'T add components (or actually modify the state of the component) within the `paint` method!!  Components should be added in the `init` method!

Answer (score 2):

**Problem #1**

You are, repeatedly, adding your buttons whenever `paint` is called.  `paint` may be called for any number of reasons, may of which you don't control. Never modify the state of any UI component in the `paint` method.

Instead, call `buttons` in the `init` method.

**Problem #2**

You are not telling the UI to update itself when you change the state of the lights.  In your `actionPerformed` method, add `repaint();` as the last statement, this will schedule a repaint of your component and `paint` will (eventually) be called

**Better solution**

Start by moving your custom painting to the `paintComponent` method of a `JPanel`.  This will allow you to isolate the painting and add the additional benefit of double buffering (stop the flickering updates)

Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Add your buttons to the `BorderLayout.NORTH` position of the applet and your lights panel to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`, this will prevent the buttons from interacting with your lights panel (overlapping it).

```
add(buttong, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(lightsPane);
```

This will require you to supply methods to control the lights panel from the applet, but it will make your life much easier in the long run

Comment: I see what your saying as far as not calling the buttons method in the paint method but when I try to put it in the init my applet does not initialize. I will check out the oracle tutorial. Also I have to use flowlayout for the buttons as a requirement for the project.

Comment: The buttons are on a separate `JPanel`, which uses `FlowLayout` by default, I'm talking about putting the panel in the north position of the applet, which is using a `BorderLayout` by default

Comment: I got the the lights to work but thats after I deleted the audio file. My question now is how do i make the audio file play when go is pressed and also I need to have a car image that moves on go and stops on slow and stop.

Comment: The audio should be controlled from the `actionPerformed` method, so would state of the car.  For the car's animation, you would probably need a `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: When I draw the image in the paint method, my applet no longer initializes. My audio wont play under in the actionpeformed method (the same code as was in it before just under the if(obj==go) section).

Comment: *"When I draw the image in the paint method, my applet no longer initializes"* makes no sense, as the `init` and `start` methods are called before the `paint` method.  Where are you loading the image?  The audio failing to play will have more to do with the inability for the applet to find the audio file then just about anything else.

Comment: I added the image in the paint method and solely after that addition my applet says failed to initialize at the bottom of its screen. I apologize for being hard to understand this is my first graphical project and also my first post on a coding forum. Also do I put the timer in the actionPerformed method where the go if statement is?

Comment: It's likely that the image failed to load and/or is `null`

Comment: Does this HAVE to be an applet.  This is going to cause you so many problems

Comment: Yes i have to upload it to a website as an applet

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.applet.Applet.getCodeBase(Applet.java:169)
 at lights.<init>(lights.java:11)
 plus more

Comment: Are you running the applet in a browser or the applet viewer?

Comment: on ecipse so I think the applet viewer

Comment: In your `init` method add `System.out.println(getDocumentBase());` and see what it prints to the console

Comment: I get the same stuff in the console. Should I remove stuff so I'm back to a working applet and retry?

Comment: i get file:/home/charles/workspace/nevermind/bin/lights1406092171869.html

Comment: Okay, so I assume that your images and audio need to be stored in `/home/charles/workspace/nevermind/bin`

Comment: Sorry to say that they are there and it is still a null pointer

Comment: `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL(getDocumentBase(), "image name"));` works just fine for more...

Comment: When I try that I get errors under bufferedimage imageio and URL do I need to import anything

Comment: You should be important `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` and `javax.imageio.ImageIO`.  `ImageIO.read` will also throw a `IOException`, which you need to catch and handle

Comment: Ok do I import java.net. URL for the URL and could you direct me to a tutorial for this type of error handling

Comment: [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: I declared the buffered image under the class and put the try catch part in the init method